# How to deploy ubuntu container to Azure Container Instance and keep it running

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, azure-container-instances

I cannot manage to deploy 'ubuntu' to Azure Container instance without it becoming "Terminated" right after the deployment. I tried setting the `command` to ["/bin/bash"], however, it doesn't stop the container from terminating.

Comment: Please share container logs and Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm using the official "ubuntu" image (https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu). There are no logs . The container just terminates right after the deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#issues-during-container-group-runtime) you can see. The docker image `ubuntu` just provides the base container, but no application runs in it to make the Container Instance in the running state. So you need to add the command in the command line to make the container instance in the running state. For example, add the command `tail -f /dev/null`.

When you do it in the portal, it should look like this:

[image]

It just keeps the container in the running state and does not output anything. So there are no logs output.

Comment: Tried that. My container ends-up in "Waiting" state. The logs are: "failed to open log file "/var/log/pods/332be5a9-853c-11ea-ac43-000d3ad84afd/ubuntu-aci-1_4.log": open /var/log/pods/332be5a9-853c-11ea-ac43-000d3ad84afd/ubuntu-aci-1_4.log: no such file or directory"

Comment: @Loreno Can you share the command you used to create the container instance?

Comment: I did it through Azure Portal. The command that I used (in the advanced tab) was, as you proposed: ["tail -f /dev/null"]

Comment: Works! Looks like it is necessary to split parts of the command into separate strings in the array. Do you know why is that? Previously I did one string in the array and it failed.

Comment: @Loreno It's the types defined for [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) in Dockerfile.

Comment: Works like a charm!